# PHP - Make manual language selector override GeoIP redirect

Tags: php, overriding, geoip

I'm using Maxmind's GeoIP redirect service, but as we know it isn't 100% accurate. That's why there's a manual language selector on the header of my website, so people who were mistakenly redirected to the wrong country can change it.

The problem is to add an exception to the GeoIP itself, to make the manual selector override the GeoIP, couldn't come up with something to do it, thought about doing with cookies but there must be a better way

```
<?php
            include("geoip.inc");
            $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $gi = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

            $country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, "$ip");

            geoip_close($gi);

            switch($country_code) {
              case "BR": header("Location: https://mysite.com/br"); break;
                          case "ES": header("Location: https://mysite.com/es"); break;
              default: header("Location: https://mysite.com");
            }
?>
Select your language:

<a href="mysite.com">English</a>
<a href="mysite.com/es">Spanish</a>
<a href="mysite.com/br">Portuguese</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the database updated in order to be as much accurate as possible, and you can accomplish this using the instructions listed [**here**](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoipupdate/), in the occasion of an incorrect IP detection, i would second your usage for cookies and i would recommend setting the cookie's life time as long as possible.